# macos: env: python: No such file or directory when I use dot slash on a .py file

Tags: mac-osx, python, path, pythonpath

I thought all I had to do was add things to my path and pythonpath but MAC os still cannot find Python when I do a ./myfile.py  etc...

my .zshrc:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"
export PYTHONPATH
```

But nothing I can source .zshrc or open a new terminal to be sure and if I say:

```
./myfile.py
```

I get the error:

`env: python: No such file or directory`

Do I have to also alias python to python3???

Comment: I think your file may have the wrong shebang

Comment: It had no shebang, but I fixed it by having a sym link:   ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python  probably stupid on my part but was not obvious and took some hunting, I will leave this here incase it helps someone else do it faster.